# How can I append two list items to one item with two items inside? (Python)

Tags: python

How can I append two list item into one item, with those two items inside?

```
    tN2 = []

for i in range(13):
    j1 = tN1[0][i]
    j2 = tN1[1][i]
    tN2.append(j1 and j2) #This does not work but illustrates what I want to do.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use nested lists :

```
tN2.append([j1,j2])
```

Or a tuple :

```
tN2.append((j1,j2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use list comprehension.

```
tN2 = [(tN1[0][i], tN1[1][i]) for i in range(13)]
```